# How to find the Div elements along with the input elements through jquery selector string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The queryString to find all the input elements with ID ends with '-0', '-1' etc ..
the below code works fine

```
var queryString = ':input:focusable[id$="-' + index + '"]';
```

I also want to find the div elements ending with the same scenario .. How i can change the query ??

Comment: var queryString = 'div[id$="-' + index + '"]';

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
var queryString = ':input:focusable[id$="-' + index + '"], div[id$="-' + index + '"]';
```

Using [comma](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) `,` you can add selectors to the same query string.

**Edit**

> but the select element am having present inside the div element and
>   the div element has the ID

try this

```
var queryString = 'div[id$="-' + index + '"]:input:focusable';
```

Comment: I can find the div elements ... but am not focussed in the div element .... I am working in a scenario when i click the TAB button it should search all the input elements and focuss one by one in the list ... but the select element am having present inside the div element and the div element has the ID .. so i need to focuss that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma to add additional selectors:

```
var queryString = ':input:focusable[id$="-' + index + '"],div[id$="-' + index + '"]';
```

Comment: I can find the div elements ... but am not focussed in the div element .... I am working in a scenario when i click the TAB button it should search all the input elements and focuss one by one in the list ... but the select element am having present inside the div element and the div element has the ID .. so i need to focuss that ...

Comment: @kumaran I don't think I understand you correctly. Can you explain a bit more? Maybe you have a live example?

Comment: @kumaran I did not understand the focussed part. What do you want to do with it? You want to select only focused div element?

Comment: The scenario is i need to focus all the input elements one by one by click of TAB button  ... So am writing a query to search all the input elements ... the query works fine ... when i have the id in the select element ... but the select element in my case is not having the id .. instead the div element outer to the select element is having the id .... So i need to focus the div element when TAB button click

Comment: try this query: `:input:focusable[id$="-' + index + '"], div[id$="-' + index + '"] :input:focusable`

Comment: Super ... It works fine ... thanks a lot ... there is one blocker ... now i get focused to the select element ... next i am clicking the TAB button .. the current element (select) is now sending into the function .. where i need to send the div element into the function ... Is there any check if it is the select element v need to take the parent div element .. ??

Comment: @kumaran it depends on what framework you are using, if this is vanilla JS you need to check `nodeType` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType property if it's equal `SELECT` and then just grab parent node `parentNode` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing JS code you are using. Please provide how do you get that stuff working

Comment: function findNextElementInTabOrder (currentElement) {
                        return findFieldInRelationToField(currentElement, 1);
                    }

Comment: show `findFieldInRelationToField` function source code and update your answer

Comment: i cannot post all the code can you give your mail ID .. it exceeding the limit